# R error: (abline) cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r, graphics

I'm getting an error in my R program that says:

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

Here is my code, I can't figure out where it's coming from:

```
n=900000
plot(density(rt(n,n-1)),xlim=c(-10,5),main="",xlab="")
abline(v=t,col="red")
```

Comment: `t` is a function (**t**ranspose).

Answer (score 4):

The error is referring to you accidentally passing a function name (`t`) instead of a numeric as x-coord of your abscissa, as @nrussell said:

```
abline(v=t,col="red")
```

I think you meant `T`/`TRUE` and assumed the v/h-arguments to abline were booleans, but they're not, it needs numeric coords (if it was only a boolean, how would it know where to put the abscissa?):

```
abline(a = NULL, b = NULL, h = NULL, v = NULL, reg = NULL,
       coef = NULL, untf = FALSE, ...)

Arguments:

a, b: the intercept and slope, single values.

   h: the y-value(s) for horizontal line(s).

   v: the x-value(s) for vertical line(s).
....
```

Anyway in this case you want to put it at x=0:

```
abline(v=0, col='red')
```

Don't forget, R is case-sensitive, so `t` is not `T`/`TRUE`. This ain't Lisp, baby...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar problem by converting the "closure" type to numeric type using: `as.numeric(t)`